# How to make the redirect file have a custom order

Tags: command-line, io-redirection

This is my test `.sh` file.

#### errorandoutput.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo myecho
ls dflj
```

If I run `./errorandoutput.sh >file 2>&1`,then we can get such `file`

[image]

But I hope the `STDOUT` information is after the `STDERR`.So I change the command into

```
./errorandoutput.sh >file 1>&2
```

But I get a empty `file`.How to make the the `STDOUT` information is after the `STDERR` in a redirect `file`?

---

I mean I hope I can get a `file` like

```
ls: cannot access 'dflj': No such file or directory
myecho
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how order of redirection work.

The order of redirection only determine the order of action the shell does with file description, not its content.

In:

```
./errorandoutput.sh >file 2>&1
```

First, the shell redirect standard out to `file`, then redirect standard error to standard out, which is now pointed to `file`, so both standard out and standard error now go to `file`.

At this stage, the shell is done with redirection. It has nothing to do with content of file `file`.

The order of content in `file` is determine by the order of commands you ran inside script. Change your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls dflj
echo myecho
```

and you would got what you want.

Answer (score 0):

the '**>**' acts like "1**>**"

this way it should work

```
./errorandoutput.sh  2>file  1>&2



$ ( echo yay ; fhgfhgf ) > out 2>&1
$ cat out
yay
bash: fhgfhgf: command not found
$ ( echo yay ; fhgfhgf ) 2> out 1>&2
$ cat out
yay
bash: fhgfhgf: command not found
```

Comment: But I get a same [file](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ootli.png)

Comment: sorry i misunderstand , i saw the 'But I get a empty file' , i thought you wanna inverse FDs order,

Answer (score 0):

If it's important, send the standard output to a file and then output it afterwards. This would of course require a script:

```
temp=/tmp/yc$$
yourcommand > ${temp}
cat ${temp} && rm -f ${temp}
```